# Rails 4 - Model Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a marketplace app in Rails 4. When entering products, sellers can enter a price and a saleprice. SalePrice is optional.

My current validations below check for values greater than 0. How do I add a validation for - saleprice must be at least 5% lower than price.

```
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than: 0}
validates :saleprice, numericality: {greater_than: 0}, :allow_blank => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use custom validation

```
validate :saleprice_lower_than_price

def saleprice_lower_than_price
  if (saleprice != nil && saleprice > (price - (price * 0.05))
    errors.add(:saleprice, "Sale price should be 5% less than price")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own custom validation method, 
there is a good explanation in the rails guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom validation method

```
validate :saleprice_lower_than_price

def saleprice_lower_than_price
  (price - saleprice) > price * 0.05
end
```

Optionally you can add condition in this method to add errors to your object, like

```
errors.add(:saleprice, 'should be lower')
```